# Django-Photologue : Error 500 while uploading jpg files but uploading png files works

Tags: django, photologue

When I try to add jpg files in django-photologue I get "Server Error (500)".

The apache logs show :

> "POST /admin/photologue/photo/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 330
>   http://www.mywebsite.net/admin/photologue/photo/add/" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

The file is actually uploaded to the media folder on the server but it doesn't show in the admin interface and I cannot add it to a gallery.

Also adding png files works just fine.

Any suggestions please?

EDIT: When I enable django's debug I get

Exception Type: UnsupportedOperation Exception Value:   fileno Exception Location:  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/photologue/models.py in create_size, line 455 –

Comment: if it is a non-production environment, just set DEBUG to False, and see the exact error message. It is extremely hard to speculate what might be wrong

Comment: I get this when I enable debug : 
Exception Type: UnsupportedOperation
Exception Value: 
fileno
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/photologue/models.py in create_size, line 455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the version of Django I was using (1.6). I updated to the latest Django release and it fixed the problem.

Comment: First I updated Django from 1.6.7 to 1.6.11 and it worked. But not for long. In the end I downgraded ``photologue`` from 3.1.1 to 3.0.2. Now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

As karthikr has already said: it's very hard to offer advice if you supply no error messages/only part of the error message.

However, you state that JPG files cause an error, while PNGs work well. This would suggest to me an issue with [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) on your platform; Pillow is a dependency for Photologue, and can be very troublesome to install (and get working correctly). Try googling 'Pillow jpg', together with the name of your operating system.